# System.Windows.Forms.Keys as the argument for SendKeys.Send

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I need to send `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enum with the method `SendKeys.Send(string keys)`.

How do I convert `Keys` enum to string compatible with this method?

I can do `switch` and try if the key is one of incompatible keys, like this:

```
string toSend = "";
switch(keys)
{
     case Keys.Backspace:
          toSend = "{BS}"
          break;
     case Keys.F2:
          toSend = "{F2}"
          break;
     // ...
     default:
          toSend = keys.ToString();
          break;
}
SendKeys.Send(toSend);
```

But I want to know, if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: SendKeys is VB6 legacy.  Harks from a very different time, no support for the Windows key for example.  It didn't yet exist in 1998.  Pinvoke SendInput() to do what you want to do, like SendKeys does.  Lots and lots of Google hits.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, I'll try to Google more...

Answer (score -2):

You can write as
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}"); 
SendKeys.Send("E");